# Combining two MySQL tables that are loosely connected

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb, normalization

So I have two MYSQL tables in a DB which aren't connected (two different data sources) [around 500,000 rows in each].  They have things like Business Name, Business Address, City, State, along with some specific information in each that I hoped to populate a third table with once I've figured out how to 'link' the two together.

My initial thought was to try to link them together if the Business Name / City / Address were the same.

The issue is, for a lot of rows, there isn't an exact match between the two tables.  So in one the business name might be 'XYZ' in another 'XYZ Incorporated', same goes for some addresses, it could be '123 NW 10th St.' or '123 Northwest Tenth Street'.

So now I'm trying to figure out a way to find a 'close enough' match, and that's where I'm lost.  Never done anything like that before, and wouldn't know where to start.  My thoughts were I'd be able to set some kind of threshold where if the match is close enough, I'd insert the two IDs into another table linked the two together for future processing.

(Databases are currently InnoDB / MySQL)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Have you ever used `LIKE` in a query?

Comment: Of course, but that won't work... the texts aren't exact matches and that would result in a huge chunk not working.  So if I were to search for XYZ Inc, it wouldn't match XYZ.  Also, there could be 10 XYZ in different cities (or multiple in the same city).  So I'd have to pair that with a LIKE on the locality as well, and that'd match very little.  I'm more looking for a  way to find a close match, on multiple terms, and say find something that is a '90%' match.

Comment: `LIKE '%XYZ%'` might work. It would certainly catch more.

Comment: This is more complex than it seems. I think trying to write something that would do this automatically is going to have extremely low ROI. Honestly, your best bet is to make the matches you can, and then take the leftover rows and farm them out on something like Mechanical Turk to be reviewed by a human being.

Comment: No matter what I expect to get some loss, it's just that if I try to run it all through LIKE statements, I lose A LOT.  The Answer below from infomaniac is pretty close to what it looks like I'll need.  My thoughts were to weight each match, and if it is above a certain score, insert the two matching IDs in a new table.   If I can get it to work, even if I need to let it run on the server for a few days, that'd be fine since it's a one-off.   So if I can match 90+% that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `View` which combines the two tables. In order to find out which fields match most closely, I would recommend using either a "Levenshtein" distance, or something a big smarter like "Jaro/Winkler". I went through something similar to this a while ago and I blogged about it.

http://dannykopping.com/blog/fuzzy-text-search-mysql-jaro-winkler

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I'm trying to do, thanks a lot!

Comment: Since I'd be running this through a million records, could you recommend anything to speed it up / how would you modify it to provide a score based on multiple columns (I'll probably be weighting each as well).

Comment: Do you need to do this continually or once-off?

Comment: It'll be a once off.  My thoughts were to run this on the Business Name, and then the address / city / state (and weight each).  So if the business name matches, that's a big indictator.  Then since there are a lot of businesses with the same name, but different locations, further qualify / weight it based on that.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking.  Even if I need to let this run for a couple days that'd be fine.  Can you make any recommendations on the best way to run it on multiple columns?  I'll probably be able to figure it out, just wanted to see what your thoughts were since you've done it already.

Comment: Best guess (without knowing what your data looks like): pick a 10% random sample of data (`SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5000`), and test against what you think will be the best match - in this case, Business Name (I'd say). First categorise those, store the match and the confidence factor, and then run it against the other columns (with `AND` clauses), and see if your accuracy improves. Remember, this is fuzzy. It won't be perfect

Comment: Yea, I expect to lose some in the process.  But this looks like it's exactly what I need.  Thank a lot for your help!